# TFS: different .NET framework projects in the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a TFS project that has multiple .NET 3.5 projects.
I want to create a windows phone 8 project in the same solution cause it will reference a a .NET 3.5 library project and a WCF project.

when my colleagues get the latest version from the TFS, they can't load the solution cause they don't have Visual Studio 2012 (which is used for the windows phone project).

is there a way to add my windows phone project to the TFS solution without affecting the other older framework projects ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add your project normally (Add Existing project to source control), but when you chenck in, you don't check in your solution file. with this solution you save your code in repository without affecting basic behavior